All elections you did not vote for have results with a dead link to OpaVote download page
This is what the election result usually looks like when you did not vote in that election (example from Islam but I can reproduce it on Solana and Board & Card Games and probably plenty others):

One of the hyperlinks is broken. The target no longer exists.
Hyperlinks are really poorly visible nowadays, so I'll show it again with Darkreader enabled and the offending part marked in red:

The hyperlink in 'OpenSTV software' points towards https://opavote.com/download, which no longer exists:

This only happens with elections you did not vote for. Elections you did vote for have a different modal that does not contain that specific link.

Regarding "Hyperlinks are really poorly visible nowadays", it's only for visited links. Until you visit a link, it's fine and in the color it used to be in the past. For whatever odd reason, SE decided to drastically change the color of visited links, making it same as ordinary text. (You can see all links as "not visited" by opening a page in Guest/Incognito mode.)

@ShadowWizard I don't know why they override the colours at all. It kinda makes sense on the sites where that's part of the design, but on sites where it's not… And frankly, for accessibility reasons, there needs to be a way to say "use the colours I've specified in my user agent". Currently, when I do a forceable override in my user agent (Firefox: it's in Settings → General), sections of the site become invisible. (Though this is better than it used to be, so they're clearly doing work on it!)

@wizzwizz4 no idea, and the way it's handled, by changes they make, getting negative feedback, change again, rinse and repeat... over and over - is just horrible. No idea who is to blame, but something in the very core isn't working properly.

@ShadowWizard Yes, but it's something in the very core of the entire software industry (nay, the entire tech industry). See this anecdote from 2013 GitHub. Judging from outside, Stack Exchange seems to be one of the least bad at this sort of thing. (Not saying there's no room for improvement, of course: there's loads! But just adding some perspective.)

openSTV been unsupported a while, and availability of the desktop client's been a bit spotty. In better times, I suspect the community would have forked it, or SE might have maintained a FOSS repo for a fork. Not sure what's the 'right'/practical solution here
